# IntellijIDEA doesn't see my jars, what do I do?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Using Java and IntellijIDEA, I was writing a script, which worked up until the moment I updated IntellijIDEA. Now I get an error of:

```
Error:(2, 43) java: package org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions does not exist
```

This obviously annoys me a lot. I tried to download the jars from https://poi.apache.org/download.html and https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/openxml4j. I added both jars as "File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> + -> Apply -> OK", but no positive result... I still have the same errors.

Additionally, I am importing my old script from GitHub using IntellijIDEA's  "Import" oprion on the start menu. I then reuse the my old settings. I used gitignore my rep to not sync some of the Intellij's custom files.

Comment: Maven? Plain lib? Rebuild project?

Comment: Add the poi jar to the module as dependency: [Module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies)

Comment: Not a Maven, importing by Intellij's default "Import Project" function. Maybe that's what's causing the issue... Any good tutorials on Maven / Grandle etc??